# Yii2 console command pass arguments with name

Tags: yii2

I want to use commands as

```
php yii sync anyvar2=anValue  anyVar1=anyValue
```

In controller

```
 public function actionIndex(){
       echo $anyVar1;
       echo $anyVar2;
   }
```

I tried with php yii sync [--anyvar2=anValue ,--anyVar1=anyValue]

Comment: Have you tried adding the variables as function arguments?

Comment: yes i tried using optionAliases,options ,  it worked but its very complicated because need to declare each variable in public , options function and optionAliases function

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1) If you want to set controller parameters:

```
class SyncController extends \yii\console\Controller
{
    public $anyVar1;
    public $anyVar2;

    public function options($actionID)
    {
        return array_merge(parent::options($actionID), [
            'anyVar1', 'anyVar2'
        ]);
    }
}
```

Now you can set them like that:

```
php yii sync --anyVar1=aaa --anyVar2=bbb
```

2) If you want to just pass variables as arguments:

```
public function actionIndex($anyVar1, $anyVar2)
{
    // ...
}
```

Now you can set them like that:

```
php yii sync aaa bbb
```

Answer (score 3):

Got solution

when need to pass variable in console

1. Variable should declared in **public** scope.
2. Variable should returned in **options function**

   Ex:

   ```
   class SyncController extends \yii\console\Controller
    {
     public $anyVar1;
     public $anyVar2;

   public function options()
   {
     return ['anyVar1','anyVar2'];
   }
   public function actionIndex(){

     echo $this->anyVar1."\n";
     echo $this->anyVar2."\n";
   }
   }
   ```

   In console

> php yii sync --anyVar2=1111 --anyVar1=999

Comment: It should be: `public function options($actionID)`